# Change color of misspelled words in vim-lexical

Tags: highlight, spell-checking

How can I change the color that is used to highlight misspelled words in vim-lexical?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The repository](https://github.com/reedes/vim-lexical) says it uses Vim's spellcheck, so you should be able edit your color file's SpellBad highlighting to do this. Something like:

```
hi SpellBad ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

You could also put these in your vimrc, but your color file is really the proper place for it.

- cterm is for terminal vim
- gui is for gVim

The full set of options are `cterm ctermbg ctermfg gui guibg guifg`. You can use `:help` on those terms for more information.

You might also think about changing `SpellLocal` and `SpellCap` if you wan't to change Vim's other spell check colors.

Comment: In some cases it is good idea to reset highlighting to the defaults before applying new style: `hi clear SpellBad` and then `hi SpellBad ...`